# Haskell pattern match on content of list

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have a list of elements:

```
data Foo = A Int | B Int | C Int

myList :: [Foo]
myList = [A 1, B 2, C 3]
```

I want a function that gets the value of a specific constructor, if existing:

```
-- returns value of the first A constructor, if exists:
getA :: [Foo] -> Maybe Int

-- returns value of the first B constructor, if exists:
getB :: [Foo] -> Maybe Int
```

Any elegant solution?
And what about a `getX` function, capable of getting the value of any specified constructor in the list?

Answer (score 3):

This will work

```
getA theList = listToMaybe [x | A x <- theList]
getB theList = listToMaybe [x | B x <- theList]
```

You will need to import `Data.Maybe`.

Generalizing this would be possible, but tricky....  What type would you even want this function to have?  (`[a]->somethingToRepresentAConstructor->Int`).

Comment: Thanks, thats elegant. I always forget about list comprehension.

Comment: Regarding the generalization, the somethingToRepresentAConstructor could be a String?

Comment: Hmmm, doing this is certainly possible....  Doing it in an elegant way, that is another question....  The brute force approach would be to write it out by hand `getX "A" = getA; getX "B" = getB`.

Comment: My list of constructor is quite long, that's why I was thinking of generalizing. Would be elegant to have one function for them all...

Comment: Maybe using view patterns? or something-something patterns

Comment: Two thoughts that come to mind....  Base something on show/read strings, or use Template Haskell.  The first soln gives me the heebie-jeebies :) , the second soln is complicated to implement.  But from a practical viewpoint, one of these might be exactly what you are looking for.  There might be a view pattern soln here, I haven't used them a lot myself, but perhaps you can take the general form above and replace with a generalized pattern.

Comment: Instead of three constructors all with the same arguments, use one constructor with an enum type as its first argument. `data FooType = A | B | C deriving Eq` `data Foo = Foo FooType Int` `firstOf :: FooType -> [Foo] -> Maybe Int; firstOf f xs = listToMaybe [i | Foo t i <- xs, t == f]`. Then if you want you can just define `getA = firstOf A`, `getB = firstOf B`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

> And what about a getX function, capable of getting the value of any specified constructor in the list?
>
> Regarding the generalization, the somethingToRepresentAConstructor could be a String?

You can generalize a bit more and get

```
firstJust :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> Maybe b
firstJust f xs = case filter isJust (map f xs) of
                   x : _ -> x
                   [] -> Nothing

getA = firstJust f
  where f (A x) = Just x
        f _ = Nothing

getB = firstJust f
  where f (B x) = Just x
        f _ = Nothing
```

Comment: This is what I have currently, but I didn't like it because there is one function per constructor.

Comment: Not really. You just represent each constructor type-safely, by a function instead of a string. Of course, it is less compact (though with `LambdaCase` extension you can write `firstJust (\case { A x -> Just x; _ -> Nothing })`).